# Why is the number next to the review panel link incorrect?

Tags: bug, review

Hi I'd like to know why the number next to the review link on top of the website page always indicate the number of available suggested edits and not the number of all the review tasks available. I doubt StackOverflow is a bugged website so my guess would be that there must be a reason for it.
However I can't make myself a reason why it would still show up the available suggested edits when I reviewed my daily 20. Why for instance it is not showing me the number of available late answers to review, since it is most of the time 0 I think that would be useful.

Comment: It's not a bug, it's by design.

Comment: So it is purely intended to show the suggested edit numbers? And ignore the other available review tasks?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Ok thanks, why was it decided to be so?

Comment: Because an indicator of pending suggested edits was an important enough feature to be implemented at some point in time, while an indicator of other pending review actions wasn't.

Comment: Ok thanks :) And why was it decided to also keep it even after the daily 20 suggested edits done?

Comment: The question is why they don't remove it after you have completed your suggested edits.  That feature wasn't important enough to implement.

Comment: They don't remove it because there are still remaining edits in the queue. You already know you've reached your limit, because you're not able to review more suggested edits. I wouldn't think it's important enough to warrant the work to implement turning it off when you reach your review limit, and doing so would technically be wrong. (Unless, of course, there really are no edits to review available in the queue for *anyone*.)